# Remove or override the "Clear Button" on UISearchDisplayController in a UIPopoverController on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

When using UISearchDisplayController with a UISearchBar in iPad it is displayed in a UIPopoverController. I would like to override the clear button as shown on the image to make further fixes. If that is not possible, how can I remove the clear button?

[Clear button http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg692/scaled.php?server=692&filename=537870177.png&res=medium](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg692/scaled.php?server=692&filename=537870177.png&res=medium)

Answer (score 0):

i did that once .. i replace the clear button with a custom button to make a custom action .. please check this

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = yourSearchController.searchBar;
UITextField *searchtextfield = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
UIButton *cButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20 , 20);
cButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cButton setImage:[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"yourButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//your button image.
cButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[cButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//This is the custom event
[searchtextfield setRightView:cButton];
[searchtextfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry actually meant the clear button not the cancel button.
This explains the little button at the right in the searchfield.
I edited the question to say the clear button. But thanks for taking the time.

Comment: yeah and my answer for this button :)

Comment: Updated the pic for clarity ;-)

Comment: ok why don't you make your popOver for display the results then you will have the full control to change what you want ?