# Custom clear button in UISearchBar text field

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I tried:

```
UITextField *searchtextfield = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    UIButton *cButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    cButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20 , 20);
    cButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//your button image.
    cButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [cButton addTarget:self action:@selector(xButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//This is the custom event
    [searchtextfield setRightView:cButton];
    [searchtextfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

But it doesn't work very well...
It displays custom button, but when you type something, the old one get's back...

How can I do this?

Comment: follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799074/how-to-override-the-cancel-button-in-the-uisearchbar/13799144#13799144

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set a custom clear button in a UISearchBar try this:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyClearButton.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Don't forget to set an image for `UIControlStateHighlighted`

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HighlightedClearButton.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. If someone is looking for the Swift version of this code, it can be found there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419881/1447641

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. I thought I had to do it with the UISearchBar object instance.

Answer (score 7):

You need the following

```
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is strongly recommended to place strings in this order starting from *UIControlStateHighlighted*
in case you want to use the same image: image1=image2=image.

In iOS7 it is weird but fact that direct order of UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateHighlighted doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your cancel button on `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

And the most amazing you can also hide you clear button by

```
UITextField *textField=(UITextField*)[[searchBar subviews]objectAtIndex:1];
textField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Follow my answer foe more info [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799074/how-to-override-the-cancel-button-in-the-uisearchbar/13799144#13799144)

Comment: no its for cancel button @Mert , its already clear from function name setShows"Cancel"Button

Comment: Yes, your answer is for cancel button, but @1337code has asked about clear button.

Answer (score 0):

Set `clearButtonMode` to  `UITextFieldViewModeNever` and `rightViewMode` to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.2, following code worked for me

```
        [UISearchBar .appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "search_clear_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: .Clear, state: .Normal)]

    [UISearchBar .appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "search_clear_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: .Clear, state: .Highlighted)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Swift` **4.2, 4.1+** of [malex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066428/malex) answer,

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "image1"), for: .clear, state: .normal)
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "image2"), for: .clear, state: .highlighted)
```

I also answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345642) to set `clear button` `tintColor` along with `results button` customization.