# UISearchBar cancel button not responding

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I have implemented searchbar which shows cancel button once user has focus in searchbar. For this I have written `searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;` in my `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method. In `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`, I resign the keyboard so that user can view full tableview.

Problem: At this point the searchbar cancel button is not responding. It only responds once searchbar gets focus again. Is this the default property of search bars cancel button or am I missing something in my code. I want to use cancel button without giving the focus in searchbar again.

Comment: how do you resign firstresponder on the textfield of serachbar ?

Comment: have you checked my answer.?

Comment: Its true... by design or not, it ought to work if it is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is search bar cancel button's default behaviour. If you want other functionality, you can just uncheck cancelbutton property for search bar and can use `UIButton` as cancel button.

Comment: Thanks !! I will try to implement my own cancel button

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you can** make your `UISearchBar` cancel button responding.
By default it is disable but your can access it's sub view and then set enable to cancel button.

```
for (id object in [mySearchBar subviews])
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *searchBarCancelBtn = (UIButton*)object;
        [searchBarCancelBtn setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Follow this answer if you want some other logic [Custom clear button in UISearchBar text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862050/custom-clear-button-in-uisearchbar-text-field/13862943#13862943)

Answer (score 3):

I think its a default behavior of `UISearchBar` when it gets focus then and only then the cancel button will be enabled. You cannot get cancel button event of `UISearchBar` when it has no focus.

So My suggession to achieve your task is,

- Create a ToolBar
- Insert `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view as `UISearchBar`
- Insert `UIBarButtonItem` named "Cancel" with action

Answer (score 0):

The above method stopped working, this is tested and working on iOS 17.0:

```
- (void)enableCancelOnSearchBar
{
    [self enableButtonsForView:self.searchBar];
}

- (void)enableButtonsForView:(UIView*)view {
    NSArray<UIView*>* subviews = [view subviews];
    [subviews fbl_forEach:^(UIView * _Nonnull value) {
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [(UIButton*)value setEnabled:YES];
        } else {
            [self enableButtonsForView:value];
        }
    }];
}
```

`fbl_forEach` curtesy of `FBLFunctional`[https://github.com/google/functional-objc]
.