# customizing UISearchBarIconClear for UIControlStateHighlighted does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar for which I have set a custom UISearchBarIconClear for UiControlStateNormal.

```
[mySearchBar setImage:myImage forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This part works as it should but unfortunately when tapping the clear button, it changes from the image I set, to the original default gray one.

I have tried setting the image for UIControlStateHighlighted, but apparently that does not work.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW26) actually states

> Valid states are UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled.

What's the point of setting a custom button for the default state if you can't set it for the highlighted state? Am I missing something? Any thoughts or workarounds appreciated, thanks!

Comment: for me, this works perfectly... even the highlighted state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across the same issue a little bit earlier today, here is my really ugly workaround that I probably wouldn't use myself.

```
for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    if([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]){
        UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)subView;
        CGFloat myWidth = 26.0f;
        CGFloat myHeight = 30.0f;
        UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, myWidth, myHeight)];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbariconclear"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbariconclear"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearsearchbar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        searchField.rightView = myButton;
        searchField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    }
}
```

And then..

```
- (void)clearsearchbar {
    for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]){
            UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)subView;
            searchField.text = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Three problems with this approach..

1. Since we're digging around inside the subviews of the searchbar it could break some day with an OS update.
2. This doesn't behave exactly like UISearchBarIconClear, in that the clear icon will always be visible.. You could potentially try testing with other UITextFieldViewModes using this approach, I didn't mainly because, from what I know none of the others would be ideal here, for some reason or the other.
3. Maybe it's just me, but I don't really think that something that introduces two problems when trying to solve one, is a solution. :-)

If anyone has a better way of tackling this problem, I'd love to hear it too.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've done some similarly hacky stuff to make other modifications to the underlying textfield and search bar styling. This solution seems like it would work fine in general, but I will most likely pass on it because this is not a critical thing for me to change (as you said, solving a problem by creating 2 more). That said, you could make this behave like the regular clear button by hiding/showing the button when the textfield text changes based on whether there is anything in the field.

Comment: @BenJackson: Wow! Thanks of that clever question in a comment. Ideally, I would would say, I would post a solution that I wouldn't use myself, for the same reason, you would ask the question you asked. What would an answer to that question accomplish?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and adjusting the order of the statements solved it:

So instead of doing `UIControlStateNormal` first then `UIControlStateHighlighted`, set the image for Highlighted state first

```
[searchBar setImage:clearIcon forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[searchBar setImage:clearIcon forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: What is this madness?

Comment: It is always the strange ways that work. This should be accepted as the actual answer rather than messing with the subviews. As suggested its likely to change and not great at all... Thanks for this thought.

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Answer (score 2):

How about using appearance proxy?

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], [UISearchBar class], nil] setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as you described with the clear icon reseting to the default icon upon being pressed.

This seems to be due to me trying to use the same UIImage for both the normal and highlighted state, switching to a different image for the highlighted state fixed the problem.