# How to change the text in the Clear Button from the SearchDisplayController on iPad with Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin

[image]

I need to change the text shown by the "clear" button in the search results shown in the picture.

The language set on the iPad is Spanish, but the button text remains in English, that's why I need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is same kind of question:

[Remove or override the "Clear Button" on UISearchDisplayController in a UIPopoverController on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704562/remove-or-override-the-clear-button-on-uisearchdisplaycontroller-in-a-uipopove)

Here in answer, it is explained how to add custom button in place of Clear button.

Hope this helps